# Find and replace special character

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following script :

```
sed -i -e 's/±|±/±~±/g' /tmp/file.txt
```

the problem is that in notepad i can see the character ±|± but not in Unix. in Unix there is ▒|▒ (Extended ASCII character 177). Is there any way to translate it??

Comment: will be a solution using unicode in regex, thats only a idea

Comment: You don't want to "translate" by replacing your data. Instead you want to take care that all components involved here use the same character encoding, preferably unicode (UTF-8). Then all components will interpret the data the same.

Comment: how can i use unicode n regex for this character ± ???  @arkascha the full script will replace the character and then will create an output in csv nothing else :)

Comment: Take a look at the tr(1) command. Maybe it is not what you are looking for, but its purpose is to TRanslate (find/replace, or even delete) characters.

Comment: Your example works without any issue for me, the sequences are replaced when it is executed in my unixoid environment. I suspect that your `notepad` application does not save data in UTF encoding. If I remember correctly, then `notepad` is an MS-Windows application? If so then most likely that is your issue: MS-Windows is well known to have troubles with unicode support, it internally typically uses some 8bit encoding ("win-something codepages"). You'd have to check that first.

Comment: im using Notepadd ++ which is setted to UTF encoding.. is tehre any option to have the roblem in server side??? which use SunOS ??